# "'int' object is not callable" Error When Trying To Plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, callable

Here is my code,

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Voltages 
V,I = np.genfromtxt('Photocurrent_graph_2.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',', 
                    usecols=(0,2), skiprows=1, unpack=True)

z = np.polyfit(V,I,6)


def function(x):
    return (z[0])*x**6 (z[1])*x**5 + (z[2])*x**4 + (z[3])*x**3 + (z[4])*x**2 + (z[6])*x + z[7]

plt.plot(V, function(V))    
plt.plot(V,I,'ro')
```

If I comment out the line plt.plot(V, function(V)), python does not give me any errors. What have I done wrong?

EDIT:

I followed iCodez's suggestion, but am not provided with a new error messsage,

```
return (z[0])*x**6 + (z[1])*x**5 + (z[2])*x**4 + (z[3])*x**3 + (z[4])*x**2 + (z[6])*x + z[7]
IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
return (z[0])*x**6 (z[1])*x**5 + (z[2])*x**4 + (z[3])*x**3 + (z[4])*x**2 + (z[6])*x + z[7]
```

You forgot a `+` between `(z[0])*x**6` and `(z[1])*x**5`.

Here is the fixed version:

```
return (z[0])*x**6 + (z[1])*x**5 + (z[2])*x**4 + (z[3])*x**3 + (z[4])*x**2 + (z[6])*x + z[7]
```

Without the `+`, you try to call `(z[0])*x**6`, which is an integer, by placing `(z[1])` directly after it.

Comment: Oh, yes. See, I was trying to see whether or not I missed a *, neglecting to see if I missed a +. I fixed that, but now I am getting this message: IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7

Comment: Is the error due to z[7]? I figured that that would be the y-intercept.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I actually did this very thing. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You missed **+** sign after the first expression.
You use too many brackets - they do not add to clarity of the code, and just make it unreadable
And there's a better way to write polynom calculation:

```
sum(c*x**pos for pos, c in enumerate(reversed(z)))
```